# PHP date with 30 mins added, is reversed when inserted into MySQL datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date

I believe I'm going mad.

```
$expire = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+30 minutes") );
```

It works as expected when echoed, yet when I insert it into a custom table via the wordpress database class, into a `datetime` column it's showing current time minus 30 mins.

Am I mad?

Comment: Have you controlled the column type&date format in the table? So you are passing the correct date format?

Comment: so it's 1 hour off?  Check the timezone..

Comment: I would suggest you check the server timezone. And add a field to do automatic timestamp update.

Comment: Legends, it was the timezone. Many thanks folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply given the time frame you are working with, it makes me wonder if you are seeing a Standard/Daylight time conflict, assuming you observe daylight savings time where you are.

First, See if you experience the same issue with "+60 minutes" as a test. If it is then -60 in the database, then it may be a bug, however, if it is then the current time in the database, it may actually be a timezone issue.

Make sure all of your timezones are properly configured on your host OSes and in your database. If the database column is of the type "timestamp" then mysql [converts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) it to UTC on storage, and back on retrieval, so a mis-configured timezone could cause a 1 hour offset there as well.

Hope This Helps!

Answer (score 0):

All date and time functions are now dependent upon a correct timezone setting.

You can either do this in your script

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');  // for example
```

OR
Check your php.ini for this setting

```
date.timezone = UTC
```

And set it correctly for your specific timezone, here is a [List of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) which you will need either way